# Armature Rigging Problem

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

I have a problem with rigging my Indominus Rex.
I have joined all the components of the body for a simple rigging test. I have parented the dinosaur to the armature using automatic weights, and as expected, the inverse kinematics control bone is causing a mesh deformity when moved.

[image]
[image]

However, the real issue is that when I try to fix the weights using weight painting, only one side of the Rex has any actual weight. This does not allow me to fix the mesh deformities.

[image]

A side problem (which may be related) is that some of the spines and claws arbitrarily choose not to move in pose mode!

[image]
[image]

Any help is much much appreciated!

Comment: hello, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I've shared the file.

Comment: I've tested and the parenting With Automatic Weight is rather good, and the weight painting works on both parts, it needs corrections of course, but I'm not sure what you mean when you say that "when I try to fix the weights using weight painting, only one side of the Rex has any actual weight"

Comment: When you go to weight paint mode, only one foot has the weight paint on, even though it is identical.

Comment: Oh wait a minute, I found the solution. I'm really sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: so what was your problem? when you parent, if you don't want a bone to be taken into account, disable its Deform option in the Properties panel > Bone